# How to make an inline DataTable editing

Tags: jquery

I have this code in my app:

```js
var editor;
$(document).ready(function() {
 

    var t = $('#nuevoart').DataTable({
           columns: [
        {title: "COD.:" },
        {title: "NOMBRE" },
        {title: "MARCA" },
        {"title": "P/U" },
        {title: "CAT.:" },
        {title: "SUBCAT.:" }
    ], 
        language:{
                        "sProcessing":     "Procesando...",
                        "sLengthMenu":     "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
                        "sZeroRecords":    "No se encontraron resultados",
                        "sEmptyTable":     "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
                        "sInfo":           "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
                        "sInfoEmpty":      "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
                        "sInfoFiltered":   "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
                        "sInfoPostFix":    "",
                        "sSearch":         "Buscar:",
                        "sUrl":            "",
                        "sInfoThousands":  ",",
                        "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
                        "oPaginate": {
                            "sFirst":    "Primero",
                            "sLast":     "Último",
                            "sNext":     "Siguiente",
                            "sPrevious": "Anterior"
                        },
                        "oAria": {
                            "sSortAscending":  ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
                            "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
                        }
                        },
 
    
          responsive: true });

            
$('#addRow').on( 'click', function () {
        t.row.add( [
            'ALFANUMERICO ',
            ' PRODUCTO',
            ' MARCA',
            'PRECIO ',
            'CATEGORIA ',
            ' SUBCATEGORIA'
        ] ).draw( false );
 
     
    } );
$('#nuevoart').on( 'click', 'tbody td', function () {

} );

});
```

And i create a DataTable with Jquery plugin, i achieve inserting new row with the values above. But i would like to be able to editing a row by clicking on certain field in order to insert new record with the content. Is it possible?

[image]

Comment: Refer this: https://github.com/pandeyz/Jquery-Datatable---Server-Side-with-Custom-Inline-Editing

Comment: But my problem is how to create each field of the record with class "editable" in order to use your example. Because im not obtaining data, i just want to insert a new record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i used the code above by Mayank and now it funtions perfectly, but i made some changes:

```js
 var oldValue = null;
   $(document).on('dblclick', '.editable', function(){
    oldValue = $(this).html();
    $(this).removeClass('editable'); // to stop from making repeated request
    
    $(this).html('<input type="text" style="width:150px;" class="update" value="'+ oldValue +'" />');
    $(this).find('.update').focus();
   });
   var newValue = null;
   $(document).on('blur', '.update', function(){
    var elem    = $(this);
    newValue  = $(this).val();
    var empId = $(this).parent().attr('id');
    var colName = $(this).parent().attr('name');
   
   
     $(elem).parent().addClass('editable');
     $(this).parent().html(newValue);
   
   });
```

The code to add a new row is like that:

```
$('#addRow').on( 'click', function () {
    t.row.add(
     $('<tr><td class="editable">ALFANUMERICO</td><td class="editable">NOMBRE</td><td class="editable">MARCA'+
     '</td><td class="editable">PRECIO</td><td class="editable">CATEGORIA</td><td class="editable">SUBCATEGORIA</td></tr>')[0] ).draw( false );


} );
```

Each column is editable class.